# Bind the error data of datagridrow to a tooltip textblock

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am trying to show the validation error message of data grid row in a tooltip. Here is the code that works when I use the ToolTip property of the Grid control directly (wihtout styling):

```
<Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                                <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" 
                                         Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                                         Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                                           FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />                            
                            </Grid>
```

Now this shows the tooltip correctly. Everything is fine.

**Problem:**

As soon as I start styling the ToolTip separately, the binding stops working somehow. Here is the code that I am trying which does not work:

```
<Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2">
    <Ellipse x:Name="ErrorEllipse" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" 
           Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
           Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
           <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
               FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
               <Grid.ToolTip>
                   <ToolTip Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                       <Border >
                           <TextBlock Text= "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                                                       MinHeight="20"
                                                       MinWidth="100"
                                                       Foreground="White"
                                                       Background="Red"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Grid.ToolTip>
             </Grid>
```

What am I missing here and how can I achieve the proper binding? Probably its something basic but I have no idea...

Comment: It's not the styling is your problem. A tooltip is not in the visual tree. It's a popup. Hence your relativesource will find no datagridrow.  You need a resource that's in the visual tree and grab that or placementtarget.  Here's a super simple explanation of your issue https://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/wpf-tooltip-content-binding  Which you should have googled, by the way.  Also. No errors will be a problem for [0] use / instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should style the ToolTip separately with a ControlTemplate.

```
<Style x:Key="ValidationToolTipStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    ... 
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                <Border >
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        MinHeight="20"
                        MinWidth="100"
                        Foreground="White"
                        Background="Red"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then in your XAML, use the ToolTip like this:

```
<Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2">
    <Ellipse x:Name="ErrorEllipse" 
        StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" 
        Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
        Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
    <TextBlock 
        Text="!" 
        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Foreground="White" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
       <ToolTip 
           Style="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipStyle}" 
           Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Grid>
```

I hope this helps.